# Building time Countdown

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a time countdown, I'm sending an timestamp in milliseconds, and every second I subtract this value to the current time to get the countdown.

I'm using this website to generate the timestamp

```
https://www.epochconverter.com/
```

But when I choose the timestamp day to be in three days for example, my script only checks the hour, minutes and seconds, and forgets about the day, month or year.

Example: When I choose this date - 11/04/2017 20:00:00

My script doesn't show my exacly how many hours does it take reach the timestamp, It shows, 3 hours which is incorrect

My code:

```
var updateTime = setInterval(function() {
    var getEpochEnding = new Date(1492111767000);
    var getTimeNow = new Date();
    var timeZone = getTimeNow.getTimezoneOffset();
    var ctdMillis = new Date(Math.abs(getEpochEnding - (getTimeNow - (timeZone * 60000))));

    var ctdSeconds = parseInt((ctdMillis / 1000) % 60);
    var ctdMinutes = parseInt((ctdMillis / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    var ctdHours = parseInt((ctdMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

    if ((getTimeNow - (timeZone * 60000)) > getEpochEnding) {

        ctdSeconds = 0;
        ctdMinutes = 0;
        ctdHours = 0;
        clearInterval(updateTime);
    }

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = ("0" + ctdHours).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + ctdMinutes).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + ctdSeconds).substr(-2);

}, 1000);
```

JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/udec8074/1/

Comment: Instead of writing this logic yourself you may consider using momentjs (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Comment: In the line `var ctdHours = parseInt((ctdMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24)` the `% 24` means the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) after dividing by 24. So, for example, 75 would be changed to 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `% 24` from `ctdHours` expression and change `ctdHours` in `innerHTML` expression:

```
    var updateTime = setInterval(function() {
    var getEpochEnding = new Date(1492111767000);
    var getTimeNow = new Date();
    var timeZone = getTimeNow.getTimezoneOffset();
    var ctdMillis = new Date(Math.abs(getEpochEnding - (getTimeNow - (timeZone * 60000))));

    var ctdSeconds = parseInt((ctdMillis / 1000) % 60);
    var ctdMinutes = parseInt((ctdMillis / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    var ctdHours = parseInt(ctdMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60));

    if ((getTimeNow - (timeZone * 60000)) > getEpochEnding) {

        ctdSeconds = 0;
        ctdMinutes = 0;
        ctdHours = 0;
        clearInterval(updateTime);
    }

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = ctdHours + ":" + ("0" + ctdMinutes).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + ctdSeconds).substr(-2);

}, 1000);
```

Though this solution won't show leading zero for hours: "1:23:45" instead of original "01:23:45".